# Forgot su password at virtual machine?

Tags: linux, su, fedora-17

I'm new to `Fedora-17` and `Linux.`
I've stumbled upon a problem after created my su password;
I added some sequence and after this see prompt `Setup is complete!`
But generally I didn't remember this password.

It's a VMware virtual machine (on a Windows XP system).

**Question:**
 - How to solve this trouble on the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hold CTRL key during boot
2. Add `1` to end of boot entry
3. `b` to boot
4. `passwd` to change your password

Full instructions here:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password

Comment: Can you display `Hold CTRL key during boot` - How to do this option?

Comment: Shutdown the VM, hold the CTRL key on your keyboard, start it up and keep holding key until you see the book menu.  Lots more details in the link :)